# Combining Two Queries with Similar Actions to One

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query below that gives me the total number of hours in a year that a person walks greater than 2 mph Unioned with a query on the total amount of entries (total number of hours recorded). Both are basically the same query with the exception of the last clause in the first one. The issue is that it takes a good 30 seconds to run this query. Is there a way for me to combine the two queries to make it run faster but get similar data? My end goal is to get the percentage of time a person walks greater than 2 mph.

```
SELECT COUNT(STARTING_HOUR) FROM SENSOR.SPEED
FULL OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT.ID
ON SENSOR.SPEED.Account_ID = ACCOUNT.ID.Account_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT.NAME
ON ACCOUNT.ID.Account_ID = ACCOUNT.NAME.Account_ID
WHERE UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Sarah%'
AND UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Jones%'
AND STARTING_HOUR >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-
DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
AND STARTING_HOUR <= TO_DATE('2015-12-31T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-
DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
AND Value > 2

UNION

SELECT COUNT(STARTING_HOUR) FROM SENSOR.SPEED
FULL OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT.ID
ON SENSOR.SPEED.Account_ID = ACCOUNT.ID.Account_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT.NAME
ON ACCOUNT.ID.Account_ID = ACCOUNT.NAME.Account_ID
WHERE UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Sarah%'
AND UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Jones%'
AND STARTING_HOUR >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
AND STARTING_HOUR <= TO_DATE('2015-12-31T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you've changed the query for posting,  ut even so, `UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Sarah%'` looks odd as it can never be true. And your statrting-hour filters are not catching anything after midnight on the last day of the year.

Comment: Hi Alex, that is correct. I changed the data a little bit for censorship but essentially it would be taking in all uppercase inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, full outer join is totally superfluous.  Then table aliases make the query easier to write and read.  And then you can do the arithmetic using `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN VALUE > 2 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM SENSOR.SPEED s JOIN
     ACCOUNT.ID i
     ON s.Account_ID = i.Account_ID JOIN
     ACCOUNT.NAME n
     ON i.Account_ID = n.Account_ID
WHERE UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Sarah%' AND
      UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%Jones%' AND
      STARTING_HOUR >= DATE '2015-01-01' AND
      STARTING_HOUR <= DATE '2015-12-31' ;
```

I'm pretty sure the `WHERE` clauses turn all the outer joins into inner joins.  Perhaps you do want an outer join somewhere, but it is not obvious that any are necessary.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the first date; and the value > 2 filter at the end should have gone, surely?

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thanks for answering; however, what i needed was the total hours a person ran above 2 mph/total hours rather than the average speed above 2 mph. MT0 was able to get what I want but are there other techniques I can use to speed up the query? Thanks again!

Comment: @J.D. . . . This doesn't return the average speed.

Comment: Let me try it again!

Comment: I gave it a try again but it only gives me either a 1 or null

Comment: @J.D. . . That's because I brilliantly left the `value` condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: Yes! It works great now! Only takes 3 secs to run the query, thank you! I just to digest what it is doing now so i can use it in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(1) = 0   -- Handle division by zero
         THEN NULL
         ELSE COUNT( CASE WHEN value > 2 THEN 1 END )
              / COUNT( 1 )
       END AS Percentage
FROM   SENSOR.SPEED
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT.NAME
       ON SENSOR.SPEED.Account_ID = ACCOUNT.NAME.Account_ID
WHERE  UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%SARAH%'
AND    UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%JONES%'
AND    STARTING_HOUR BETWEEN DATE '2015-01-01' AND DATE '2015-12-31'
```

Do you need the `ACCOUNT.ID` table? Instead, could you join directly from `SENSOR.SPEED` to `ACCOUNT.NAME`?

I am assuming that `NAME` is in `ACCOUNT.NAME` and with the `UPPER(NAME)` filter this will never be `NULL` so you can do a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Depending on which table the `STARTING_HOUR` column is in, this could be further simplified to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hi MT0! This is exactly what i needed. The query only takes 15 secs to run now. I still needed that extra join since i needed that table to look up the person name. That middle table links the sensor id with the account id which links to the name. I made a mistake on my posting and it should of been ON SENSOR.SPEED.Sensor_ID = ACCOUNT.ID.Sensor_ID

Comment: Are there other techniques i can use to speed it up even more or is this it?